# How to stop completion of action on ngrx effect when error occurs

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

When I do a store dispatch, an error(500) happens in the effect. What I want is that once an error occurs, this stops the action from further propagating.
Ideally, the action stops so that it's like if the action was never dispatched. Even the store should not change. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to have the effect return an empty observable because I read this causes the composed observable to complete and its subscribers are unsubscribed - that's part of the Observable Contract.

However, I am unable to return an empty observable. Please advice. I have left in all the things I tried in the comments.

Effect

```
@Effect() getArea$: Observable<Action> = this.actions
    .ofType(areaActionTypes.AREA_FETCH)
    .map((action: areaActions.FetchAreaAction) => action.payload)
    .mergeMap((areaPayload: IAreaPayload) =>
        this.areaService.getArea(areaPayload)
        .map(area => {
            return new areaActions.FetchAreaSuccessAction(area);
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          // original way I had it which does NOT prevent the
          // observable from completing and the handling of this action continues
          return of(new areaActions.FetchAreaFailAction({ error: err.message }));

         // NONE OF THESE BELOW WORK. CODE DOESN'T EVEN RUN BECAUSE 
         // THE EFFECT IS EXPECTING A TYPE Observable<Action>

         // return Observable.empty();
         // return Observable.of(Observable.empty());
         // return of(new areaActions.FetchAreaFailAction(Observable.empty()));
       })
);
```

Just to try a different approach, I also tried doing this in the Effect

```
    .catch((err: any) => {
       return ErrorObservable.create({type: areaActions.FetchAreaFailAction, payload: err});
```

and then in the actions

```
export class FetchAreaFailAction  {
  readonly type = AREA_FETCH_FAIL;

  constructor(public payload?: any) { }
}
```

and then in the reducer

```
switch (action.type) {
   case areaActionTypes.AREA_FETCH_FAIL:
     return Object.assign({}, state, {
       area: null,
       loading: false,
       loaded: false
     });
```

but this continues handling the action all the way and even puts this null data in my store which is exactly what I was trying to prevent.

Comment: Try `Observable.of(new areaActions.FetchAreaFailAction())`. This is the correct response (looking at your rxjs version). Post any errors you get after using this.

Comment: bc1105, I made the change and it made no difference. The propagation continued and went on into the reducer. Perhaps this is where I should do something to prevent the action from completing but now sure how.

Comment: If you want to cancel our the state change you should create an Undo action, and undo the state change yourself. The effects will be called after the action went through all the reducers.

Comment: I have had the same action seemingly fire again after catching an error, and the problem was that in my actions I was using the same string for both the success and error action identifier - effectively it was a copy and paste bug.